# Fetch Icecat API for product information

Tags: php, json, api, symfony, pim

For creating my own Product Information Manager I get the SKU & EAN/UPC from our vendor. But get the pdf and correct product information I want to use the information which I get from the Icecat API.

The information which I need should be possible with the free Icecat version. But receiving this:

{"statusCode":4,"message":"Product identifier(s) is not correct"}

The EAN is working in the Icecat UI.

https://live.icecat.biz/api/?UserName=Username&Language=en&GTIN=4710614535640

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://live.icecat.biz/api/?UserName=Username&Language=en&GTIN='. $EAN .'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json')); // Assuming you're requesting JSON
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($response);
```

I had 500 product and only 15-20 worked. Is there a workaround to get the product information with the free version?